# Do you have to pull up vinyl flooring before tiling bathroom floor?

Tags: flooring

Do you have to remove old single layer of vinyl flooring before tiling?  What is best to use for under lay would it be backer board over vinyl?

Answer (score 1):

There's usually some type of underlayment beneath the vinyl.  When I did my kitchen floor, it had luan board.  I would remove the vinyl.  You really just need to remove the luan board and the vinyl comes for the ride.  Then you can put down cement backerboard or even the rubber membrane.

Unfortunately/fortunately, the luan board is stapled down, which is easier than if it was glued down, but there's a lot of staples.

Answer (score 0):

no - but it depends on the installation.  if the vinyl is in good shape (not loose or coming off in big chunks) then you can leave it.  also, try driving a few staples into the floor.  if it breaks into chunks or fractures (as oposed to just sinking in and holding), then you will have to pull it up.

next:

1)  staple metal lath down over the whole area, lapping each piece by 3 inches or so.  staple with a half inch staple every 3 inches in all directions

2)  pour a good quality polymer modified scratch coat mortar down over the lath and level with a trowel

3)  proceed to lay your tiles

this method results in a much stronger floor than just laying tile over backer board or some such shortcut method.  the floor is mechanically stronger and more tightly bound to the old floor structure